# Building model to recognize patterns in files

Tags: machine-learning

I have some files ,all follows some pattern say their first would be more or less then some lines would talk about similar things and then some lines have same content in each files
Given a large number of files like this , I want to train a model that can tell whether a new file has the same pattern as all other files are following or not.
I have many groups of such files , each group of files follows a different pattern i.e each group of files talks about a different topic , I want to build a model using machine learning concepts so that it works with all groups of files

Comment: Do you know the total number of groups?

Comment: Nope, The condition is that one group files will more or less follow the same pattern

Comment: You might want to define a distance between two such files / texts (check the Levenshtein family of distance metrics) and try a clustering algorithm (hierarchical clustering or k-means run with different values for `k`).